# Could not autowire field JpaUserRepository (JpaRepository)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I try to connect JpaRepository to work with Hibernate.
But I cannot autowire it like this.
I see error: **Could not autowire field JpaUserRepository.**

```
@Autowired
private JpaUserRepository jpaUserRepository;
```

My Repository:

```
public interface JpaUserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

What I missed?

My HibernateConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.springapp.mvc.repositories")
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("password");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("jpaData");
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.springapp.mvc.models"});
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter(){
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution myself. I upgraded spring to version 4.1.7 and it works.